# AWS RDS MySQL innodb/btr_search_latch

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I am running MySQL 5.7.24 on AWS RDS, I have an InnoDB type table and working fine with normal traffic but when send push notification to 50k user the problem happend.

server features 32 GB RAM, 8vCPU, and my AWS RDS server is db.m5.2xlarge.

the **wait/synch/sxlock/innodb/btr_search_latch** take resources greater than **wait/io/table/sql/handler** like below image

the **innodb_adaptive_hash_index** enabled now

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You're trying to send 50,000 push notifications in five minutes?

50,000 / 300 seconds means you're pushing 167 notifications *per second* and I assume then updating the database to record the result of the push. Probably you are doing this in many concurrent threads so you can do the pushes in parallel.

Have you considered doing these push notifications more gradually, like over 10 or 15 minutes?

Or updating the database in batches?

Or using fewer threads to avoid the high contention on the database?

I used to work for SchoolMessenger, a company that provide notification services for the majority of public schools in the USA. We sent millions of notifications, SMS messages, and phone calls every day. The way we did it was to have a very complex Java application queue up the notifications, and then post them gradually. Then as the results of the pushes came in, these also queued up, and updated the database gradually.

We used MySQL, but we also used it together with [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org) as a persistent queue. Push all the tasks to be done into the queue, then a pool of worker threads would act on the tasks, and push the results back into another queue. Then a result-reading thread would read batches of results from the queue and update the database in bulk updates.

When you are designing a back-end system to do large-scale work to do, you have to think of new ways to architect your application to avoid choke-points.

As a database performance and scaling consultant, I have observed this rule many times:

*For every 10x growth in data or traffic, you should reevaluate your software architecture. You may have to redesign some parts of it to work at the larger scale.*

Comment: you mean the heavy traffic related to write to database not view because the sql/handler take small resources and push notification not send from my sytem it's send from webengage .i can pushes as parallel like 10K - 15k every minutes. and i think the problem realted to hash index in innodb

Comment: You could try `innodb_adaptive_hash_index = 0` to disable the adaptive hash. But this may be balanced by making some secondary index lookups slower. Also I am not 100% certain you can set that option in your RDS parameter group.